# UIDatePicker hours are disabled

Tags: iphone, uidatepicker

I have a UIDatePicker object and I am setting it up as follows but for some reason my hours field is disabled on the current date but minutes are not. Not exactly sure what I am missing,  any help would be appreciated.

```
UIDatePicker *picker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] init];
picker.date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:DATE_MIN_SECONDS_OFFSET];
picker.minimumDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:DATE_MIN_SECONDS_OFFSET];
```

This is what My datepicker looks like
http://img.skitch.com/20100417-d75gq78pjwjb9d37ku9msmcduc.png

Answer (score 2):

It appears to be a [known bug](http://openradar.appspot.com/7760755).

Comment: Was this ever fixed?  I'm still running into this on firmware 4.1 (simlulator)